# Should Developers Conduct Sanity Testing in Public Dev Environment, if they Tested Locally and Wrote Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, architecture, .net, devops, angular

Should Developers conduct Sanity Testing in Dev Public Server, before sending code over to QA team?

We are developing a Property Application. Our company utilizes C# .Net Core with Angular, and Devops process in Azure cloud.

1. After software engineer codes and tests locally; by getting all latest changes from Azure Git repos;
2. We finalize code and write automated unit tests (thru Xunit and Karma/Jasmine)
3. Additionally, developers point local database to Developer Environment Public database, to gain access to wider range of data.
4. Finally, we send application to Dev Public Environment for Basic Smoke Test

and then eventually to QA environment through Azure Devops deployment.

Our QA team is complaining, 'Developers should not only Smoke Test, but Sanity Test to ensure all the functional changes are there'.

Smoke Test is different from Sanity testing, https://www.guru99.com/smoke-sanity-testing.html  https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/smoke-testing-and-sanity-testing-difference/

Smoke Test ensure application  basically functions, (eg does not render a blank webpage, and APIs actually are turned on. Now as far as other things sanity testing, like correct html layout, exact property tax calculation is seen; that we leave out as its conducted in steps above.

Our philosophy is, we have already tested Locally, and Then Pointed Our Database to actual Dev Server, and write Unit Tests. Why do Sanity testing Again? If things are not properly deployed correctly, why even paying Azure licensing fees to Microsoft for Github and their Devops services? We trust they work.

The truth is, some people are not writing code properly EVEN on local environment which is causing problems for QA. However, they are prescribing a incorrect solution to a problem.

Comment: The original "sanity test" definition is a good analogy here - are you expecting a developer to diagnose their own potential insanity? Because insane people generally think of themselves as sane.

Answer (score 4):

> However, they are prescribing a incorrect solution to a problem.

Then find a better one. Your current methods are failing you. QA proposed a solution that would work. If you think that's not the root cause, go find it. In the meantime, do what QA is asking so they can work properly.

Personally, I would do sanity testing. I *do* sanity testing. Why would I not? QA is there to *assure quality*, not do basic testing for me. They have a job to do and being my assistant for tasks I find boring is not one of them. I don't want to be caught with my pants down. If QA finds a mistake, I want to be able to say "bummer, I just did the whole new process in that environment this morning successfully, what did I miss?" instead of looking like a clueless idiot that doesn't know their own software when it exploded in some unforeseen but basic way.

So yes. Sanity testing is necessary **now** because your way of not doing it failed. And you will need to do it until you at least fixed your own process and deliver working software. Sanity testing would be a good idea **later** because how else do you assure that your process of delivering working software is working correctly?

Comment: hi, I guess my question is why? considering I already did testing on Local and wrote passing automated unit tests, where they passed in both cases

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1, can you prove (to QA) that the tests you did (locally and automated) are equivalent to the sanity tests they ask for? If not, you have more testing to do. If yes, you can tick the box for sanity tests on the checklist. What QA is asking for is not just that you have tests that pass, but also that those tests cover enough of the requested functionality.

Comment: yep, and all those are being done locally, and through unit tests, ok, will talk to them

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding and (based on previous experiences) sanity tests can be considered as a part of the *regression testing* suite. You are **not creating new test cases** rather than you are **picking some from the existing ones**. It should not cover full user journey instead it should focus only on a single part of the entire application. We are doing this in order to make sure that the given component's main functionality is working for a particular release. Based on these the Sanity testing is the responsibility of the QA team.

But I would like to emphasize that (as always) you should **agree with your QA team** about the responsibilities and boundaries. 
I would also suggest to create a common/shared glossary for test categories, types and somehow capture the quality checking steps during the whole lifecycle of a feature. This will give for both teams the common understanding of testing.